# Создать класс прототип

Tags: c#

нужно создать класс-прототип для хранения и обработки экземпляров структур, наложить ограничение на параметр типа данных: элементы коллекции должны быть значимого типа, тип-аргумент должен реализовывать интерфейс IComparable
вот моя структура

```
public struct Sportsmen:IComparable
    {
        public string Surname { get; private set; }
        public int YearOfBirth { get; private set; }
        public string KindOfSport { get; private set; }
        public string Rank { get; private set; }
        public void SetSurname(string surname)
        {
            Surname = surname;
        }
        public void SetYearOfBirth(int yearOfBirth)
        {
            if (yearOfBirth > 0)
                YearOfBirth = yearOfBirth;
            else
                throw new Exception("Неверный год рождения");
        }
        public void SetKindOfSport(string kindOfSport)
        {
            KindOfSport = kindOfSport;
        }
        public void SetRank(string rank)
        {
            Rank = rank;
        }
        public Sportsmen(string surname,int yearOfBirth,string kindOfSport,string rank)
        {
            Surname = surname;
            YearOfBirth = yearOfBirth;
            KindOfSport = kindOfSport;
            Rank = rank;
        }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return ("Фамилия : " + Surname + "\nГод Рождения : " + YearOfBirth + "\nВид спорта : " + KindOfSport + "\nРазряд : " + Rank);
        }
        public int CompareTo(object obj)
        {
            return KindOfSport.CompareTo(((Sportsmen)obj).KindOfSport);
        }
    }
```

вот мой класс

```
class ClassSportsmen<T> where T: struct,IComparable<T>
    {
        T[] array;
        IComparable<T> compare;
        public ClassSportsmen(T[] listStruct,IComparable<T> compare=null)
        {
            array = listStruct;
        }
    }
```

при создании объекта класса

```
ClassSportsmen<Sportsmen> sportsmen = new ClassSportsmen<Sportsmen>(sportsmens);
```

подчёркивает Spotrsmen:

> CS0315 The type 'Sportsmen' cannot be used as type parameter
>   'T' in the generic type or method 'ClassSportsmen'. There
>   is no boxing conversion from 'Sportsmen' to
>   'System.IComparable'.

помогите исправить пожалуйста

Comment: Ошибку какую пишет?

Comment: а можно увидеть всю реализацию проекта ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IComparable и IComparable <T> - разные интерфейсы.

Решение: заменить интерфейсы так, чтобы они были одинаковыми.

```
public struct Sportsmen : IComparable, IComparable<Sportsmen>
```

или

```
сlass ClassSportsmen<T> where T : struct, IComparable
```

Comment: Большое спасибо

Comment: Пожалуйста. Если проблема решена, то поставьте галочку